# Phalcon library class calling a function within another

Tags: php, class, phalcon

Im using phalcon 2.0.0 and i am trying to call a function with in another function but from the same class like shown below, for some reason i get a blank page. And when i comment the calling of 2nd function from first, the page loads properly.

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component;

class Testhelper extends Component {

    public function f1($data) {
        $tmp = $this->f2($data);
        return $tmp;
    }

    public function f2($data) {
       return '5'; // just testing

    }

}
```

And btw im accessing the f1 function by the volt function extender like this

```
$compiler->addFunction('customfunc', function($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
                return 'Testhelper ::f1('.$resolvedArgs.')';
});
```

if someone could help me, it would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `TestHelper` `f1()` statically in Volt, where your class does not expose that function as a static.

You can change your code like this:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component;

class Testhelper extends Component 
{

    public static function f1($data) 
    {
        $tmp = self::f2($data);
        return $tmp;
    }

    public static function f2($data) 
    {
        return '5'; // just testing
    }
}
```

and your Volt function will work. However you have to bare in mind that because you are calling things statically you won't have immediate access to all the di container services that the `Component` offers like so:

```
$this->session
$this->db
```

You will need to modify your code to pick the di container using the `getDefault()`

Another option is to use the code as you have right now, but register the `TestHelper` in your di container like so:

```
$di->set(
    'test_helper',
    function () {
        return new TestHelper();
    }
);
```

and then your volt function will need to change to:

```
$compiler->addFunction(
    'customfunc', 
    function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
        return '$this->test_helper->f1('.$resolvedArgs.')';
    }
);
```